# What is a solution if you run out of alphabets in a long code in R?

Tags: r

In R for loop codes, I know `a~z` alphabets are used. Such as, `for (a in 1:10) {}`. But what if you run out of alphabets, from using `a~z`, are there any ways to solve the problem?

Comment: you generally only need unique identifiers if you're *nesting* loops.  Comments and answers here are correct about the solution, but do you really have more than 26 nested loops ... ?

Comment: Well, my code almost used all alphabets. I am a beginner, so the problem might as well happened. I felt I needed to know in preparation for future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any valid variable name in the loop. For example all the following are valid in R:

```
for (a in 1:10) {}

for (aa in 1:10) {}

for (a1 in 1:10) {}

for (index in 1:10) {}

for (my_variable_name in 1:10) {}

for (my.variable.name in 1:10) {}
```

EDIT: I will add that you should not use the names of predefined constants (ex. `pi`) or functions (notably `c`) as variables. This edit is in response to the comment of @d.b